# Looking for a Calendar App with an 'open' API for input from Python or other programming languages. Recommendations?

Tags: automation, calendar, google-calendar-api

Use Case: I would like to take tasks that are being run against my network automatically and export them into a Calendar for visualization. So a viewer could look at this 'calendar' and see what is effectively a diagram of jobs run against our servers, when they started, when they ended, etc. I need this to be automatable - so I can schedule a PowerShell or Python script to run once a day, retrieve the information, and upload into the calendar as 'events'.

Problem: I do not think Google Calendar provides support for this without a workspace account - which I don't have. Please correct me if I am wrong, but the workspace account seems to be required. Is there a better alternative? An 'open' calendar app that I can interact with using scripts?

Comment: Just as an FYI, Google Calendar API can be used with a free gmail.com account, just in case that was your concern about using Google Calendar. The difference between a Google Workspace account and a free gmail.com would be the API limits and the number of calls you can make to the service, and probably a couple of methods or parameters on each call, that are only intended for Google Workspace accounts.

Comment: I didn't realize that! I did a little more digging and you are right - it looks like Apps Script could probably do what I need, and it won't require any additional access. Thanks for the shoutout.

Comment: Definitely, depending on how you want things to be executed you can use the methods of the ‘CalendarApp’ class, or you can add the API and use the API methods instead.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, you can also set up [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) with Google Apps Script in order to run your scripts automatically based on a document change, form submission, or time for example.

Comment: Just wanted to chime back in and say Apps Scripts and its native triggers worked perfectly. I appreciate the help!